# add rows to data.frame that are calculation from existing rows

Tags: r

Given

```
x = data.frame(value = 1:3, col2 = c('min', 'min', 'max'), id = c(1, 2, 1))
```

Is there any way to group by `col3` and then average `min` and `max` then store the result in `col1`?

```
   value col2 id
1    1  min    1
2    2  min    2
3    3  max    1
4    2  avg    1 ## row I'd like to add. where "avg" identifies average of min and max
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand but this seems to make no sense. A line represents an observation, not a calculation from others.

Comment: right, i want to add an 'observation' that is the average of a min and a max (a, and b). I'll rename the variables in `x` to make this clearer.

Comment: Oops, looking at your edit my solution isn't that. Could you rename your columns ? `col1` is id and `col3` is value ?

Comment: Could you add some context ? Or add more lines so we could see the point ? From here what you want to achieve is still a bit strange (sorry for this).

Comment: What does the `id==1` means for your last line then ?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have those three columns, and each group only has 2 values (min and max) then,

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
 group_by(col3) %>% 
 summarise(col1 = mean(col1), col2 = 'Average') %>% 
 bind_rows(x) %>% 
 arrange(col3)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 3
>    col3  col1    col2
>   <dbl> <dbl>   <chr>
> 1     1     2 Average
> 2     1     1     min
> 3     1     3     max
> 4     2     2 Average
> 5     2     2     min
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this :

```
library(dplyr)
x = data.frame(value = 1:3, col2 = c('min', 'min', 'max'), id = c(1, 2, 1))
x %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(avg=mean(value)
```

This will give you the values you want, but won't append them to your dataframe.

With this few context, I'm not sure you should do so but you can `rbind` it if you really want to.